# Log from start of script, but decide on log filename during the script

Tags: bash, logs

I do not know how to write that part of bash script which enables me to write to the file which is created in the middle of the script (because it depends on user input) but I want to write output from the beginning.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
<start_of_logging>
<code>
 read -p "Enter your city: " city
 touch ${city}
<code>
<end_of_logging>
```

Script does not know what user put in `city` so if I am correct I am not able to logging from `<start_of_logging>` part or is there any workaround? I mean I want to log everything from the beginning and write it out to the file which is called like a city provided by an user.

Comment: Did you try some searching? What about this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215760/6607497

Comment: Two ways: (1) Start logging to a file as `/tmp/myIniqName`, and `mv` this file as soon as you find what the final name should be. (2) Send your log lines to an array until you find the final name, then write out the array to the file, and send subsequent logs to the real file.

Comment: Yes, it works with `mv` approach. Thanks @Paul_Pedant.

Comment: @U.Windl  I think the OP wants to log to e.g. `./Memphis.log`, including any logging done before the user enters his `city`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Today I'd strongly advise to use `mktemp` to create the log file (instead of using some fixed initial name), unless the computer is strictly single-user.

Comment: @U. Windl, I am not using a directory in here, only creating log file which is then `mv` to the specific log file which I want.

Comment: @U.Windl  Absolutely agree, but I did not want to complicate the reply. I intended `/tmp/myUniqName` as a hint (pity about the typo). I prefer to be able to identify my temporary files, and not to have `mv` actually need to copy from /tmp to HOME, so I tend to use names built like `./appName.pid.yyyymmdd_hhmmss.tmp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to summarize the comments, the code could be something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
### start logging using temporary logfile
logfile="$(mktemp)" # possibly add options to mktemp, like "-p dir" as needed

# add a message to logfile
log()
{
    echo "$@" >> "$logfile"
}
### code
 read -p "Enter your city: " city
 touch ${city}
### update logfile
newlogfile="something_with_${city}.log"
log "renaming temporary logfile $logfile to $newlogfile"
mv "$logfile" "$newlogfile" && logfile="$newlogfile"
log "now logging to $logfile"
###
```

When running the script with input "testtown", I got:

```text
Enter your city: testtown
me@pc:~> cat something_with_testtown.log
renaming temporary logfile /tmp/tmp.alKCBTV7ti to something_with_testtown.log
now logging to something_with_testtown.log
```

### Important note

Hopefully nobody enters `:; rm -rf /` (or similar) as city...

Comment: Double-quote your variables when you use them and you can guarantee the `rm` concern won't be a worry. You might want to sanitise `city` though to ensure it doesn't contain `/`

Comment: My "Important note" was aimed towards the OP, as the question was the logfile should be "$city" (as I understand it). Of course the logfile (as I suggested) could be *derived* from the city name (with some sanitizing applied).